# Multiple Segment.io tracking codes on same website

Tags: analytics

I have users with access to different properties that need to see data from the same web site.  Is it possible to run multiple Segment.io instances on the same page?  How might I go about doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Segment's `analytics.js` can only be instantiated once on the page with a single unique `writeKey`. That's how they send the data to the project. So if you try to initialize it multiple times with different `writeKeys`, that's gonna cause a lot of bugs and issues in your data and is overall highly not recommended by Segment folks.